# Adding pythonpath to bashrc not working for some users

Tags: python-3.x, bash, path

I am running my web app under the www-data user.  I created a custom module, but the www-data user can not access the module.  I've added the path to my `.bashrc` it is not showing when I run the web site.  It does show when I use `python3` from the command line different user.
In order to get the module to work I have to `sys.path.insert(-1,'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages')` in the flask application.  How do I add the path so the www-data user can access the path so I do not have to use `sys.path.insert`

Comment: Maybe try adding the path to `.bash_profile` instead if `www-data` uses a login shell.

Comment: I created a sym link and that seemed to work.  I didn't see a .bash_profile.